# Sed - replace a string with a character of another line

Tags: linux, bash, sed, command-line, text-formatting

I am trying to write a script to reformat some text.

```
pages:
  page1:
    gui-rows: 6
    items:
      '6':
        material: CAT_SPAWN_EGG
        buy: 999999999
        sell: -1
      '7':
        material: CAVE_SPIDER_SPAWN_EGG
        buy: 999999999
        sell: -1
  page2:
    gui-rows: 6
      '8':
        material: CHICKEN_SPAWN_EGG
        buy: 999999999
        sell: -1
```

The expected output would be

```
    '6':
      type: item
      item:
        material: CAT_SPAWN_EGG
      buyPrice: 999999999
      sellPrice: -1
      slot: 6
    '7':
      type: item
      item:
        material: CAVE_SPIDER_SPAWN_EGG
      buyPrice: 999999999
      sellPrice: -1
      slot: 7
    '8':
      type: item
      item:
        material: CHICKEN_SPAWN_EGG
      buyPrice: 999999999
      sellPrice: -1
      slot: 8
```

Using this `cat 0.yml | sed "/page.*/d" | sed "/gui-row.*/d" | sed "/item.*/d" | sed "s/      /    /g" | sed "s/.*':/&\\n      type: item\\n      item:/g" | sed "s/material.*/  &/g" |sed "s/buy/buyPrice/g" | sed "s/sell/sellPrice/g" | sed "s/sell.*/&\n      slot: X"` I get this:

```
    '6':
      type: item
      item:
        material: CAT_SPAWN_EGG
      buyPrice: 999999999
      sellPrice: -1
      slot: X
    '7':
      type: item
      item:
        material: CAVE_SPIDER_SPAWN_EGG
      buyPrice: 999999999
      sellPrice: -1
      slot: X
    '8':
      type: item
      item:
        material: CHICKEN_SPAWN_EGG
      buyPrice: 999999999
      sellPrice: -1
      slot: X
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a YAML parsing tool such as [kislyuk's yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) rather than a text processing tool - for example something like `yq -Y '.pages[] | .items | with_entries(.value |= {"type": "item", "item": {material}, "buyPrice": .buy, "sellPrice": .sell} | .value += {"slot": .key | tonumber})' file.yml`

Comment: When I run your pipeline of seds I get `sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unterminated `s' command`

Answer (score -1):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }
match($0,/^[^:]+:/) {
    tag = substr($0,1,RLENGTH-1)
    val = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"",tag)
    sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",val)

    if ( gsub(/\047/,"",tag) ) {
        prt()
        val = tag
        tag = "slot"
    }
    t2v[tag] = val
}
END { prt() }

function prt(   indent) {
    indent = 4
    printf "%*s\047%s\047:\n", indent, "", t2v["slot"]
    indent += 2
    printf "%*s%s: %s\n", indent, "", "type",     "item"
    printf "%*s%s:\n",    indent, "", "item"
    indent += 2
    printf "%*s%s: %s\n", indent, "", "material",  t2v["material"]
    indent -= 2
    printf "%*s%s: %s\n", indent, "", "buyPrice",  t2v["buy"]
    printf "%*s%s: %s\n", indent, "", "sellPrice", t2v["sell"]
    printf "%*s%s: %s\n", indent, "", "slot",      t2v["slot"]
    delete t2v
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk 0.yml
    '6':
      type: item
      item:
        material: CAT_SPAWN_EGG
      buyPrice: 999999999
      sellPrice: -1
      slot: 6
    '7':
      type: item
      item:
        material: CAVE_SPIDER_SPAWN_EGG
      buyPrice: 999999999
      sellPrice: -1
      slot: 7
    '8':
      type: item
      item:
        material: CHICKEN_SPAWN_EGG
      buyPrice: 999999999
      sellPrice: -1
      slot: 8
```